# orthogonal vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question: let r =  denote an arbitrary non-zero 2D vector. Find the vector - which is unique up to a scale factor of +-1 - that is orthoganal to r and has the same length of r.

So i know that to find a vector that is orthogonal to r i need to find a vector so that the dot product of r and the new vector will be 0.

but how do it go about finding a vector that has the same length of r?

Comment: Scale it up....

Answer (score 1):

Rotate by $90^\circ$:

Multiply by $J=\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$. That is, given $(x,y)$, the new vector will be $(-y,x)$, so no computation actually required.

Then $\|Jx\|^2 = (-x_2)^2+x_1^2 = \|x\|^2$, and $\langle x, Jx \rangle = x_1(-x_2)+x_2 x_1 = 0$.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^2$ is such a wonderful place...

Comment: why did you use J?

Comment: $J$ is used sometimes in the matrix representation of  the imaginary $i$.

Answer (score 0):

Again, I thought I might show how this is done in Grassmann algebra, which Hermann Grassmann designed from the start to be an algebra of geometry. This uses a Mathematica Application based on the work of John Browne.

```
<< GrassmannCalculus`
SetPreferences["EuclideanPlane", "Vector"]
```

Define a generic vector:

[image]

The first method is to take the complement, which generates the vector that fills out the 2D space. This is indicated by an overbar and ConvertComplements converts to regular vectors.

```
GrassmannComplement[vector]
% // ConvertComplements
```

Giving:

[image]

[image]

The second method is to use the general direction bivector (on the left hand side) in an interior product and then evaluate with the Euclidean metric. The bivector acts as a 90 degree rotation operator, just like the J matrix, or I in the complex plane. The circle with a bar, CircleMinus, denotes an interior product.

[image]

[image]

Giving:

[image]

[image]